# angularjs: how to make a link not clickable depending on a scope property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my html I have a link like

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

A controller is set by the route. Now when there is a controller with a property like this

```
$scope.isNotClickable = true ;
```

I would like the link to be not clickable. I tried the following

```
<a href="/" ng-disabled="isNotClickable">Home</a>
```

but that doesn't work. Now before I write a directive, I would like to know if something like this is not possible ?

Comment: I voted for Aleksander's answer, just a small notice: Disabled links would work only in IE (and I am not sure if it works in all versions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could dynamically change the href of the link to just point to the current page if isNotClickable is true:

```
<a ng-href="{{isNotClickable && '#' || '/'}}">Home</a>
```

Equivalent in Angular 1.2:

```
<a ng-href="{{isNotClickable ? '#' : '/'}}">Home</a>
```

You probably want to change the style as well, so you could add a ng-style:

```
ng-style="{true: {color: 'grey'}, false: {}}[isNotClickable]"
```

Comment: could you have a look at my [test code](http://jsfiddle.net/UHVSF/) because I cannot get it to work.

Comment: You are using Angular 1.1, so you need to use my first line: http://jsfiddle.net/mrXKC/

Comment: I tried both, but I didn't had the {{ and }}. Do you know a site where  they explain when to use a 'string', { .. } or {{ ... }} ?